# How to find occurrences in a set of numbers in a vector

Tags: r

Ive recently been put in a R coding class and I've been having trouble with this problem. Every way i try to approach this problem, my code ends up wrong. Whats the best way to answer this? thank you.

Write an R program that return the occurrences of a set of values in a vector.

For instance, if the vector is `[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,5,7,8,9,10,5]` and the set of values is `[5,4]`, then the result is 5, because in the vector there are two occurrence of the value 4, and three occurrences of the value 5.

The function accepts as input:

- a vector representing the numbers to analyze;
- a vector representing the set of number to count.

The function returns:

- a number representing the occurrences of the set values in the list of 
  numbers to analyze.

Comment: Is this your assignment? Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: look up the `match` function

Comment: Im not asking for anyone to answer it for me, im mainly looking for a way to approach this so i can have a better understanding of what it is i have to do.

Comment: `x <- c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,5,7,8,9,10,5);
set = c(4, 5);
sum(x %in% set)
`

Comment: This is what i was able to come up with, it works but it doesn't fully answer the question .      vec <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5)
occ <- function(x){
  add<-0
  i<-1
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(length(x[x==i] != 0))
      add<- add+(length(x[x==i]))
    i=i+1
  }
  add
}
occ(vec)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints that can help you create your desired function. This is not the best way, but this way has helped me a lot in understanding what I should do. This way I am talking about is breaking down your problem into examples or smaller problems.

Firstly, let us store your vector in the object `x`.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,5,7,8,9,10,5)
```

Now if we type:

```
x==4
```

we get:

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If we type:

```
x==5
```

we get

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If we type:

```
x==4|x==5
```

which asks if each element of `x` is 4 or 5, we get:

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The remaining thing to do is count the number of `TRUE` in the last output.

If we type

```
as.numeric(x==4|x==5)
```

we get

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

In fact, we can simply type

```
sum(x==4|x==5)
```

or

```
length(x[x==4|x==5])
```

to get the desired answer of 5. Another way of doing this is with the `%in%` function. Suppose we have

```
y <- c(4,5)
```

Then

```
sum(x %in% y)
```

will also give us the desired number of 4 or 5 in `x`. Now, it remains for you to write out `sum(x %in% y)` as a function in `x` and `y` to use it for arbitrary vector `x` and arbitrary vector `y`.